# TextView below ListView but is at bottom of parent, why?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, textview

I've googled much and read more on stackoverflow. But couldn't find an answer. 
This is my List View:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="k0f.de.americanfootball.AmericanFootballFragment"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_american_football">>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/league"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
        android:textColor="@color/colorDarkText"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Deutschland: GFL 1" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:divider="@color/colorListDark"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight = "1"
        />
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_hello"
            android:text="Hello World!" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I replace the text Hello World with a statistic icon from fontawesome.

When the list view es empty, the Text View is an the end of the display. Why is it not at the top under the headline?

Here are two pictures:

[image: Empty ListView]
[image: Full ListView]

Comment: what do you think this `android:layout_weight = "1"` does?

Comment: have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The textview is always at bottom because, you used `layout_weight="1"` in ListView. This means list view occupies all left out area. So even if elements occupy the space or not, the list is holding the place as its weight is set to 1. So the textView is always pushed down. I think you can't do much about it. If you avoid weight and use wrap_content, the textview might be pushed out if there isn't enough space.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this: 

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="k0f.de.americanfootball.AmericanFootballFragment"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_american_football">>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/league"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
            android:textColor="@color/colorDarkText"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Deutschland: GFL 1" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:divider="@color/colorListDark"
            android:dividerHeight="2dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tv_hello"
                android:text="Hello World!" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: A doubt. If there are more elements in the list View won't the textView gets pushed out of screen?